# Snakemake and bash script pipefails

Tags: bash, pipe, bioinformatics, snakemake

I am attempting to create a snakemake pipeline that is robust to multiple error sources. I would like to call a bash script within my pipeline. One standard procedure for alerting a user of a problem is to use the following at the beginning of a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u
set -o pipefail
```

The pipefail checks for errors when redirecting std out using pipes. My script has the following simple lines of code within it

```
# Read the first argument
input=$1

less $input | head -10
```

When I run my script using directly in the terminal using

```
bash script.sh input
```

it runs completely fine and no errors are detected.

I then wish to run this script within a snakemake pipeline in a rule as follows:

```
    shell:
        """
        bash script.sh {input}
        """
```

snakemake throws an error:

```
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)
```

If I then remove the pipefail condition

```
# set -o pipefail
```

and then re-run snakemake I have no problems whatsoever and the script executes beautifully.

Can anyone explain this interaction between a seemingly successful pipe and how snakemake treats it? (or at least give pointers to diagnose it).

Comment: Does this snakemake thing have a proper documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u
set -o pipefail

input=$1

less $input | head -10
```

Doesn't really exit clean if the input has more then 10 lines. You can check it with:

```
bash script.sh longfile.txt
echo $? # -> Prints 141
```

`echo $?` returns the exit exit code of the previous process which is 141 here because `head` broke the pipe (google *exit code 141* to know more about it).

Snakemake detects the non-zero exit code and, accordingly, fails because snakemake executes shell scripts in strict mode (google *snakemake strict shell mode*). How you want to handle the case is up to you but this should be the explanation for the seemingly inconsistent behaviour you see.

Comment: I just ran this directly in the command line and got a 0 exit code by giving the script a text file with 121 lines. This doesn't throw a non-zero exit code when I run it directly. Only when I run it within snakemake.

Comment: It would be nice if @Aidan's observation was explained in the answer. I'm facing a somewhat similar issue where snakemake run locally succeeds, but when run via a github action, results in the same error with no useful or informative error output, even with the `--verbose` flag. What explains the discrepancy?

Comment: @hepcat72 Aidain doesn't give enough information for a conclusive answer. It would be useful to have the file s/he is using, the bash script, and the snakefile, ideally stripped down to the minimum for us to try it. Regarding your comment, I would post it as a separate answer with more details.

Comment: Regarding my issue, I don't feel like I have enough knowledge of what's going on yet to formulate a well defined question (let alone answer Aidan's question), TBH. I'm just grasping at straws. Since I cannot reproduce the github action failure locally and there is no error message other than "a command failed" in the github action log, I don't know what is causing the gh error. If I find out more, I may post a question of my own.